# Photoshop CS6 brush - duplicating

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, brush

I have a design project due on Monday and my photoshop brush keeps playing up. This is slowing me down tremendously and I have tried everything. Last time I used the brush it was smooth and now it is duplicating every stroke. I want it to be smooth like a marker. I have changed all settings and still no success. Please see example images to see what I mean. [not smooth brush](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWrgD.png)

[image: smooth brush]

Answer (score 1):

try to use a spacing of 1% with smoothing checked
[image]